# debian mirror : Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: linux, debian, apt, mirror

I have a mirror server that I maintain in school.

$ uname -a
Linux CSE-Cloud01 4.0.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.2-1 (2015-05-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo apt-get update

```
......
 W: Failed to fetch http:// mirror.cs.nchu.edu.tw/debian/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch    
    W: Failed to fetch http:// mirror.cs.nchu.edu.tw/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http:// mirror.cs.nchu.edu.tw/debian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http:// mirror.cs.nchu.edu.tw/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

In mirror itself or some of my machines, It failed in the end.(some work properly.) I had tried to do the below commands that recommended, and won't work

```
$ apt-get clean
$ rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*
$ rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
$ apt-get update
```

I can't find other solution on the internet. Did anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This solved my issue

Answer (score 8):

If deleting `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` does not work...
(esp. if you're behind a proxy), **fix "Hash Sum Mismatch" like this**:

Create file
*/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy*
with this content

```
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;
Acquire::http::No-Cache true;
Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;
```

See also [here](https://gist.github.com/trastle/5722089)

Comment: Removing .../lists/* solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it seemed to be a problem on the mirror.

As stated [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/3k3khp/aptmirror_and_hash_sum_mismatches/) remove the files "InRelease" on the server and try again.

> In the /debian/dists/jessie directory there was a file called InRelease. It had a date several months back from the other files (which were mostly dated today's date).

Answer (score 1):

I this case the problem always is the difference between the hashsum stated in the `InRelease` and `Release` files located in `dist/[name-of-your-distro]/` folder.

This files are used to verify that others like `Packages.xz` hasn't been altered. When the hashsum mismatch you get the error. Unfortunately rehashing and writing the new value is not enough, because you will also need to sing both `*Release` files with a private key that you don't own... a real tedious job.

In my case I solved the problem (which in the first place was just use the local downloaded mirror) by removing the release files:

```
rm dist/[name-of-your-distro]/*Release*
```

and adding a trusted switch to the line corresponding to this repo in APT sources:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:/path/to/your/local/mirror/ubuntu xenial main
```

Note the **[trusted=yes]**

Hope this helps, and even help me in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Following helped me (considering you are su)

- apt-get clean
- apt-get autoclean
- apt-get remove
- apt-get autoremove

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem while upgrading from wheezy to jessie. The solution was to temporarily remove xz-utils package. Wheezy can't manage .xz package lists because of the old version of apt.

```
apt-get remove xz-utils
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install xz-utils
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try removing all network connections other than the internet connection before trying to update or install files.**

I just resolved this issue now. I was using wifi to connect to the internet, but also had an ethernet cable attached to a switch which was connected to another computer. I removed the ethernet cable and the hash mismatch error disappeared. It is possible that the local area network was preventing the laptop from connecting to the internet because I wasnt able to even ping google. The browser would not open websites either.